# How can I hide the password while using php trace error $e->getTraceAsString()

Tags: php, error-handling, ftp, stack-trace

In PHP web application if there is any problem through whole process I am tracing the error and sending that error in email. I am using error handler and getting stack trace through  $e->getTraceAsString().

connecting to ftp(with username, password) is also one step in application process.

So problem is:

When system throws some error while connecting the ftp. It traces everything with username and password.
I do not want to show password in email. I want to mask password in tracing string.

Is there any solution to mask the password in tracing stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help in your case, but...

You can wrap password string into some stupid value-object - constructor with password-string as argument and getter to fetch string value, DO NOT implement __toString.

Then pass an object around instead of plain string.
Fetch plain string only when you need it.

In a stack trace string it will be shown as "Object(<YourPasswordClassName>)".